# TeXniccenter doesn't produce PDF file

Tags: texniccenter

When i tried to generate view PDF file of my latex file using `TeXniccenter` i got this message as in picture

what is the problem?

[image: message]

any suggestion

UPDATE: now it produce the PDF file but it doesnt in opened it

attached log file

[log file](https://www.mediafire.com/?15020mmambfn0dk)

Comment: Did you compile (on TeXniccenter it's called Build, i think) your .tex-file?

Comment: @longtom yes builed

Comment: Does a pdf-file appear in your working directory?

Comment: @longtom no Pdf-file doesn't appear

Comment: Try to compile using the command prompt. Press `Win+R` and then `cmd`. Within the prompt, go to the folder with your tex file using `cd c:\....` (you can use Tab to autocomplete) and then run `pdflatex your-tex-file.tex` and see if some error appears.

Comment: @Sigur Yes there is some warning error appear . but why when i compiled it from texniccenter it shows 0 error and 0 warnings ?

Comment: @user1200219, this is some problems when we use some editor. Sometimes the editor ignore errors and don't stop the process. What was the error?

Comment: @Sigur ! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float. How can i make texniccenter produce pdf again as it was before this problem coming

Comment: Hum. It is difficult to say. According to the error, use `\caption{}` just before `\end{figure}` (or table or some other float). Continue using the terminal until you solve all problems.

Comment: Ah, if you want you can delete the option `-interaction=nonstopmode`.

Comment: @Sigur what this option do exactly ?

Comment: If some interaction is needed during the compilation process the engine will not stop and so you can not see the error during it. Don't worry, delete it and see what happens.

Comment: In an editor, I would not remove that nonstopmode option. What if the editor does not contain an option/button to stop the process. I'd rather instead recommend @user1200219 to give one of Texmaker or texstudio a try instead of texniccenter. They have the added bonus of coming with their own PDF viewers that support synctex out of the box.

Comment: Restart TeXnicCenter and try again. If this doesn't work, we need more detail, like the `.log` file, or a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: @Werner attached  log file

Comment: Caption outside float plus loads of other errors. It would be a good idea to post a minimal example as @Werner suggest such that we can better pinpoint the errors you make.

Comment: So at this moment, you're able to compile from the command line?  And you can open the pdf from your windows explorer?  In that case you're probably encountering config issues with texniccenter.  You might give another editor a try as @daleif suggested?

Comment: @longtom, I don't think the OP can compile from the command line, at least not without errors. Apparently his editor cannot help pinpoint the location of the errors. Not having used TC for a very long time, I do not know how it acts these days.

Comment: @user1200219: It is obvious that we're struggling with the little amount of information you're giving. Your document seems to be small enough (no more than 100 lines), so you should at least be able to post that as well (even though it might not be considered a MWE). Moreover, the problem might be on the *Viewer* portion of your settings in TeXnicCenter, yet you've showed nothing of that. Please update your post to contain the viewer settings (in the *Viewer* tab as part of the output profile). Otherwise, for now, this seems to be going nowhere.